# KML not opening in Google Earth through VB.net

Tags: vb.net, kml, google-earth

I am writing an app for opening KML file using Google earth installed on my PC. But my code is not finding the file.

This is my code:

```
Public Class openkml
    Sub kmlopener()
        Dim ge As String
        Dim gf As String
        ge = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth\client\googleearth.exe"
        gf = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth\client\abc.kml"


        Process.Start(ge, gf)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also, just typing this in command line ( DOS ) opens file :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth\client\googleearth.exe" abc.kml
```

File is present in the mentioned location. Google earth opens, but does not finds the file. I have put the kml file in different directory also, like D directory, but shows same error. Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the spaces in the path. You can add quotes to the parameter and it should work:

```
gf = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth\client\abc.kml"""
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my actual issue.